# URL Rewrite not working only for one specific path

Tags: url, url-rewrite, sitemaps, paths

I want to ask you for help regarding URL Rewrites.
As you can see here I've added the URL rewrite for this path but in the sitemap.xml file there is still not updated it's an old (target path) so the request path is not changed.
If you can help me that will be great.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Magento, or at least our current version, does not remove an URL rewrite once it has been created, whether or not the corresponding product exists in the current catalog.

Since it is only about single URL rewrite issue you should try below steps if it works for you.

In Admin go to `MARKETING` **>** `URL Rewrites`

Filter with `Target Path` = `catalog/category/view/id/219` in your case and then `Delete` it using `Actions` dropdown after selecting corresponding checkbox.

Then try to save the respective category with id **219**  in your case and check **or** add the URL rewrite manually using `Add URL Rewrite` button where you have to fill the details as shown in below image. Please change the `Request Path` by copying your existing `Request Path` what you have currently then add `Target Path` as shown in image and then select `Redirect Type` to `Permanent (301)` and save then check.

[image]

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.

Comment: Should I flush or clear cache here or everything will be fine only with saving this.
Since I'm new developer on magento and I don't know how exactly things work. Thanks

Comment: Everything will be fine, you don't need to perform any extra steps. If still it does not work please let me know.

Comment: It's still with id in the sitemap.xml... so it's not removed. I see both paths there the requested one and the target path.

Comment: have you already remove the old existing url rewrite entry before adding the new one? Currently is it showing your expected one and also one which you have mentioned in your problem?

Comment: Yes that is the problem. It is showing both URLs.

Comment: is it working correctly after you have removed the old entry?

Comment: No. That's why I commented. I removed the old entry and it's still not working.

Comment: If you are checking it in browser please try checking it in private browser window.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Its the same. Inside sitemap.xml I have the new requested path but together with old one I want to delete this old one from the sitemap.xml

Comment: I can see that change frequency is set weekly so might be that is the reason it is not updating.... can you please try changing it to daily and then let me know if it gets updated or not. Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > XML Sitemap

Comment: I changed it to 'always' but still it's not working only for this id/219. It's strange I don't know what can be the problem. Can I change something inside Sitemap class via code?